# clickable Flat list items in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I have a flat list that displays a list of item, I would like to make each item clickable.
My render function looks like this, and it works without any issue, except that it is not clickable

```
  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={formatData(data, numColumns)}
        style={styles.container}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        numColumns={numColumns}
      />

    );
  }
```

I have tried to do something similar to [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist) but it is giving me an error, any idea what's wrong with my code?

```
      <FlatList
        data={formatData(data, numColumns)}
        style={styles.container}
        renderItem={({this.renderItem})  => (
        <TouchableHighlight
        onPress={() => console.log("hello")}>
           </TouchableHighlight>
        )}
        numColumns={numColumns}
      />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this :

`renderItem` with `TouchableOpacity`. Make sure to import it from react native.

```js
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
...
...

render() {
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={formatData(data, numColumns)}
      style={styles.container}
      renderItem={({item ,index}) => (
        <TouchableOpacity 
          key={index.toString()} 
          onPress={() => console.log("clicked")}
        >
          <Icon name={item} color="red"/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
      numColumns={numColumns}
      key={numColumns.toString()} // if you want to use dynamic numColumns then you have to use key props
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: What changes you have done if you explain little bit !!

Comment: I get the same Error I was getting,  Invariant violation: Objects are not valid as a React child(found object with keys{key}) if you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: after changing my list to an Array it worked, however it shows the string on my array, but what I want it to display is this.renderItem which is a list of icons.

Comment: @DavidShapero I update the answer. Just add Icon component and pass the icon name as item from renderItem argument.

Comment: btw why TouchableOpacity and not TouchableHightlist ?

Comment: Great job man, I really appreciate your help, that's outstanding. just a question; why TouchableOpacity and not TouchableHightlist ?

Comment: You can use any of them either `TouchableOpacity` or `TouchableHighlight ` no more difference. But, `TouchableOpacity` is easy to use and make more stylelist component. https://medium.com/differential/better-cross-platform-react-native-components-cb8aadeba472 is nice blog to understand.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to import Touchable Opacity and the error you are getting , make sure `data` you are passing to flatlist is an array. So check this :

```
<FlatList
data={formatData(data, numColumns)} // this should be an array , or array of objects
renderItem={({item ,index}) => (
        <TouchableOpacity 
          onPress={() => console.log("hello")}
        >
        <Text>Hi</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

/>
```

Hope its clear

Comment: it says unexpected token for renderItem={({this.renderItem})  => (, it says invalid left-hand side in arrow function parameter

Comment: please check my code and check yours once please, inside renderItem is not same

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can iterate inside `FlatList` itself.

Working live [https://snack.expo.io/@akhtarvahid/flatlist-simple](https://snack.expo.io/@akhtarvahid/flatlist-simple?session_id=snack-session-cLlL!kIDJ&preview=true&platform=web&iframeId=8ufv48r54m&supportedPlatforms=ios,android,web&name=flatlist-simple&description=Example%20usage&waitForData=true)

```
<FlatList
      data={formatData(data, numColumns)}
      style={styles.container}
      renderItem={({item ,index}) => (
        <TouchableOpacity 
          key={index.toString()} 
          onPress={() => console.log('Clicked item')}>
          <Text>{'Hello'}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
      numColumns={numColumns}
      keyExtractor={item=>item.id}
    />
```